# Changing the function that a thread executes

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm implementing the Dining Philosophers problem in c using pthreads.
Each philosopher is represented by a thread.
Each thread needs to be able to execute four different functions.

I'm aware that I can set a thread to execute a function with:

```
pthread_create(&tid, &atr, func1, NULL);
```

That's fine, but how do I make the thread execute a different function later on (i.e. func2).

Is there a way to change the function that a thread is executing or am I off the ball entirely?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, what are the 4 functions?

Comment: Err.. if you want the thread to execute a different function, you could err.. call it?

Comment: I only understand how to call a function from the main thread that runs a program. How do you call a function from within a thread?

Comment: Just call it.  A thread is a thread is a thread.  Just call it.

Comment: @user3233706 You have started 1 thread that runs the func1 function, you can't force that thread to run something else from the outside, at least not without the func1() function cooperating. So, just go to the code of your func1() function, and add a call to the desired function there.

Comment: my book says "when a philosopher wishes to eat, she invokes the function pickup forks(int phil_number)… When a philosopher finishes eating, she invokes return forks(phil_number). How is that reconciled with your answer?

Comment: @user3233706 by having the code in your thread function, func1(), contain these lines of code: `pickup_forks(phil_number): eat(); return_forks(phil_number);` You just need a way to pass in the `phil_number` to each of your threads when you create them, so each thread can identify a different philosopher.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility, demonstrated with a single thread (aside from the main thread).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int to_run = 0;

void func0() {
  to_run = -1;
  while (to_run == -1) putchar('-');
}

void func1() {
  to_run = -1;
  while (to_run == -1) putchar('*');
}

void *func(void *data) {
  while (1) {
    switch (to_run) {
    case 0:
      func0();
      break;
    case 1:
      func1();
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("\nDONE\n");
      return NULL;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, NULL);
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    sleep(1);
    to_run = 1;
    sleep(1);
    to_run = 0;
  }
  to_run = 2;
  pthread_join(tid, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not work. 'to_run' is shared between the main thread and the newly created thread. Access to this variable needs to be synchronized. :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to change the function the thread is running. You should represent each philosopher with a thread (as you said) and each fork with a mutex.

The philosopher threads will simply run a loop of 2 functions *think* then *eat*.

*think* is just a call to sleep.

*eat* will try to acquire the 2 mutexes that represent his adjacent forks. The philosopher thread will be blocked waiting for the mutexes to unlock. once they unlock then he can lock them himself (pickup_forks) and wait a short period of time (sleep) then unlock them (return_forks).

There is more to it than that, but it should get you past your current problem.

If your program freezes on a mutex lock. Its a deadlock and you may have to revise your algorithm to stop the deadlock.